# Dropdown selected change event fire on button event

Tags: c#, windows, winforms

Here I am using 4 drop down list past `season`,`category`, `Gender` and `division`. Based on validation on `Category`, `gender`, `division` at least one needs to be selected.

```
private void cmbpastseason_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validateComboBox())
    {
        //code snippet
    }

}

private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validateComboBox())
}

private void comboBoxDept_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validateComboBox())
        //code snippet
}

private void comboBoxDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (validateComboBox())
        //code snippet
}

private bool validateComboBox()
{
    bool isValid = false;
    try
    {
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxCategory.Text))
            isValid = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxDept.Text))
            isValid = true;
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(comboBoxDivision.Text))
            isValid = true;
        if (!isValid)
            MessageBox.Show("Select any one of the category, Gender and 
                Division ");
    }}
    catch (Exception ex)
    {

    }
    return isValid;
}
```

After selecting that when I click other button on the page it trigger the event.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Place below code when ever your page loading

```
      ListBox:
      ListBox cb = (ListBox)sender;
        if (!cb.Focused)
           return;
      Combox:
        combobox cb = (combobox)sender;
        if (!cb.Focused)
           return;
```

Answer (score 0):

Please try this code

**Approach 1:**

```
bool isAnySelected=false;

public Form1()
{
    cmbpastseason.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonHandler;
    comboBoxCategory.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonHandler;
    comboBoxDept.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonHandler;
    comboBoxDivision.SelectedIndexChanged += CommonHandler;
}

private void CommonHandler(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateComboBox();
}

private void validateComboBox()
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxDept.Text) || 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxCategory.Text) ||
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxDept.Text) ||
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxDivision.Text))
        {
            isAnySelected = true;
        }
    else
        isAnySelected = false;
}
```

**Approach 2:**

```
bool isAnySelected=false;

private void cmbpastseason_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateComboBox();
}

private void comboBoxCategory_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateComboBox();
}

private void comboBoxDept_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateComboBox();
}

private void comboBoxDivision_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    validateComboBox();
}

private void validateComboBox()
{
    if(!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(cmbpastseason.Text) || 
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxCategory.Text) ||
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxDept.Text) ||
        !string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(comboBoxDivision.Text))
        {
            isAnySelected = true;
        }
    else
    {
        isAnySelected = false;
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing Selected");
    }
}
```

And Your Button Click event looks like this

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (isAnySelected)
        MessageBox.Show("There is some selection");
    else
        MessageBox.Show("Nothing Selected");
}
```

Comment: HI I tried this approach2 but I can't use button_click event.the message need to display with in validate Combobox

Comment: @sravas please try Edited answer hope this will solve your issue

Comment: No Sorry, It  is not working. and moreover it is populating  message box only for other buttons